# How to connect Heroku Postgresql to Tableau Desktop for Mac?

Tags: postgresql, macos, heroku, tableau-api

I am currently using Heroku Postgres as my cloud PostgreSQL database, and Tableau Desktop for Mac 2020.04? The Tableau Desktop for Mac can connect to Heroku Postgres database but somehow cannot query data when I start adding some visualizations. I always encountered this error:

> "Unable to connect to the server. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database."

> "Error while executing the query."

> "The table xxxxx does not exist."

Since Heroku and Tableau are under one roof (Salesforce), they have to work well together right?

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Side note: you don't need to connect PostgreSQL to anything. _Other things_ (clients) connect to _PostgreSQL_. It's an inbound connection to Postgres.

Comment: In any case, there isn't enough information here to answer. Can you provide a concrete [mcve]? Or more information about what you are trying to do? More detailed error messages? Please read [ask].